# Adding and removing event listeners with argument bearing functions

Tags: javascript

Alright, first time posting here. I have been looking at posts regarding this issue for days now and I can't find a fix.

I have a matrix of images (basically arranged spheres) with unique id's. I want to add different functionalities to said spheres. So I proceed to add event listeners. All good so far. After the first event is triggered  I want all the spheres to change their event listener, so I proceed to remove all event listeners and add new ones. **I cannot remove the event listeners.**

Adding event:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        if ((i > 1 && i < 9 && j > 1 && j < 9) && checkCorners(i, j) === true) {
            let ball = document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString());
            ball.addEventListener('click', removeBall(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

**`removeBall():`**

```
var removeBall = function(i, j) {
    return function curried_func(ii, jj) {
        let ball = document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString());
        ball.src = "./public/assets/ball_empty.png";
    }
}
```

I'm using the curried function method because it's the last method I have tried, besides retrieving object data from the e (event) argument, which did not seem to work as e was undefined. Or using a handler. Or  using binding.

Removing event:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        if ((i > 1 && i < 9 && j > 1 && j < 9) && checkCorners(i, j) === true) {
            let ball = document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString());
            // ball.somethingToRevmoveEvent?
        }
    }
}
```

I do feel the need to mention it's also my first javascript serious project so if anyone has a better solution or workaround (instead of adding and removing events 100 times for functionalities) please do share.

[matrix for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeXzg.png)
-the user should remove 1 ball , at which point the spot turns black, and then any ball can jump over another to fill the empty spot (the "jumped over ball" gets removed). I think it's a chinese checker puzzle of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the currying is nice, it means that it returns a *new* function each time it is called, rather than a copy of the same function.  You need to somehow hold a *reference* to the function that is being bound, and then use it when removing the event listener.  Without the context of the rest of your code I will attempt to pseudo-code it a bit below:

```
const eventMap = new Map();

function getMapKey(i, j) {
    return `${i},${j}`;
}

function addEvents() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            if ((i > 1 && i < 9 && j > 1 && j < 9) && checkCorners(i, j) === true) {
                let ball = document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString());
                let removeBallFn = removeBall(i, j);
                let key = getMapKey(i, j);
                eventMap.set(key) = removeBallFn;
                ball.addEventListener('click', removeBallFn);
            }
        }
    }
}

function removeEvents() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            if ((i > 1 && i < 9 && j > 1 && j < 9) && checkCorners(i, j) === true) {
                let ball = document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString());
                let key = getMapKey(i, j);
                let removeBallFn = eventMap.get(key) = removeBallFn;
                ball.removeEventListener('click', removeBallFn);
                eventMap.delete(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is untested as I don't have the rest of your code.  The principle is that each time we generate a "remove" function, we store it in the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (`eventMap` here) using a unique key based on a concatenation of the `i` and `j` values at that point in the loop.  Then, when we got to remove, pull the *same* "remove" function out of the map using the same key, and pass it to [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). 
There are other ways to do this-- this is just one option.   Adjust as needed given the larger context of your code.  Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: Alexander Nied you did it!!! It worked perfectly! The map setters and getters were a bit scrambled but it all worked neatly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding Event

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        if ((i > 1 && i < 9 && j > 1 && j < 9) && checkCorners(i, j) === true) {
            let ball = document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString());
            ball.addEventListener('click', removeBall[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

removeBall

```
var removeBall = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i ++) {
  removeBall[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 11; j ++) {
    removeBall[i][j] = () => {
      let ball = document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString());
      ball.src = "./public/assets/ball_empty.png";
    }
  }
}
```

Removing Event

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
    if ((i > 1 && i < 9 && j > 1 && j < 9) && checkCorners(i, j) === true) {
      let ball = document.getElementById(i.toString() + j.toString());
      ball.removeEventListener('click', removeBall[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suggest you use event delegation instead of touching event listener to 100 or more elements one by one. You can read [this post](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) on how it works. Then, you just need to add one event listener to the parent node of all your images. If you want to remove the event listener, it's simple, just use `removeEventListener` by passing your event listener previously defined. So, there is no need to massively add and remove event listeners.

For example, assuming you have the following html structure, and your ball is an `<img>` element:

```html
  <div id="image-container">
    <img id="[Image Id]">
    ...
  </div>
```

You can add event lister like this:

```
  let imageContainer = document.querySelector('#image-container');
  imageContainer.addEventListener('click', removeBall);

  function removeBall(event) {
     let ball = event.target
     if ( ball && ball.nodeName == "IMG") {
         ball.src = "./public/assets/ball_empty.png";
     }
  }

  ...
```

and remove event listener

```
  imageContainer.removeEventListener('click', removeBall)
```

Later, if you want to add a different listener, and remove it later. Just repeat the above steps. Hope it helps ~